# Is it possible to reference a VS2005 website project from another project in the same solution?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, web, assemblies, c#-2.0

I'd like to add nunit testing to a VS2005 C# ASP.NET website project - so that I can excercise methods in the App_Code directory.
It's recommended that the tests are added as a seperate assembly so that the testing code does not get delivered with the website - in this lies my question:

When I add a new project into the solution which holds the website and try to add a reference to the website project it does not show up in the projects tab - is it possible to reference a website project from another project (without having to convert the website project into a web application project)?

Comment: Cheers Magnus. I extracted the classes (moving the Website project down a folder level within it's original folder in wwwroot so that the ClassLibrarys could sit next to it - to fit with our SVN deployment useage).

As an added bonus to the ability to Unit Test is the fact that it has also increased compilation speed - quite significantly on slower PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to extract the classes you have in your App_Code folder and place them in a separate project. Reference that new project in your web project. You will now have a better separation of your projects and classes, and can unit test your classes separately.